# Is it a coincidence that distance between Sun and Earth=(Distance between Earth and Moon)*(365.25+24) or is there any logical reasoning behind it?

Tags: earth, sun, distance, moon

Here $365.25$ days is the time taken for Earth's Revolution around the Sun while $24$ hours is the Earth's rotation.

Comment: It is entirely unclear why you would think this is *not* a coincidence, given that this is specific to the different units you've chosen for the earth's revolution and rotation.

Comment: First, the Moon has somewhat elongated orbit so every month the Earth-Moon distance covers range from ~ 360000 km to ~ 405000 km. Both the Earth-Moon distance and Earth's day change with time.

Second, the definition of the hour is not related to any movement of planets. It's just a choice made by the ancient people to divide the day by a nice number. So your "+24" is completely arbitrary.

Comment: There is no known mechanism that would tie the ratio between sun-planet to planet-sattelite distances and planet year to planet day together. We also don't see any such relation for other planets

Answer (score 2):

Since 365.25 represents time in days and 24 is time in hours, this must be just a coincidence.  Its a bit like adding kg to lbs - it doesn't make sense to mix units.

In addition any multiplicative factor should be dimensionless (since it's a ratio of distance to distance) whereas in this example the dimension is time.